# Android and Signing .apk File Problems

Tags: android, code-signing

Okay, so I first do the following in:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>
keytool -genkey -v -keystore -keystore.mycompany 
-alias keystore_mycompany_android -keyalg rsa -validity 10000
```

(I fill password, organisation, city and country)

I then do the following in:

```
D:\DevTools\SunJava\1_6_0__19\bin>
jarsigner -verbose -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts" 
"W:\eclipse-android-keytools\apk\myapp.apk" keystore_mycompany_android
```

I then enter the same password, but get error:

> jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore
>   was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Am I doing anything noticably wrong? (Yes, I should update the SDK)

Comment: did you use this tutorial to generate it? http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your project in Eclipse, you can use command: File -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Application. Then you will see simple creator to sign your exported apk and also you can generate key there to sign your application, if you don't have it yet.